# How can redux actions be tested?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

Let's say I have a classic redux structure: action, components, containers, reducers.

I am using a popup example here

For the **action** I would have:

```
closePopup () {
   return { type: this.actionTypes.CLOSE_POPUP };
}

close () {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(this.closePopup());
      dispatch(otherAction());
   }
}
```

**component:**

```
...
<button onClick={this.props.onClose()} />
...
```

**container:**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onClose () {
    dispatch(popupActions.close());
  },
});
```

**reducer:**

```
case actionTypes.CLOSE_POPUP:
      return {
        ...state,
        isClosed: true,
      };
```

So this is a classic workflow. I have a button that calls a method from the container which calls the `close()` method from action.js and that dispatches some methods and one of them dispatches an action that changes the state.

I want to test if the `onClose` method from container.js is changing the state as I expect.

As an example, it should be something like:

```
describe('close', () => {
  it('should change state', () => {

    // expect(container.onClose()) to change state to { isClosed: true }
  })
})
```

How can I achieve this?
Is this a common pattern in testing with redux? because I cannot seem to find examples.

Comment: **Don't test javascript, and don't test third party code.** Test your code. A unit is the smallest testable part of any software. Test your reducers in isolation to assert they update state correctly. Test your UI/props in isolation to assert when a button is clicked a passed callback is invoked. Once you've developed a suite of unit tests then you can build upon proven code and move to what you're asking, which is more of an integration test and not really something you want to do in your unit tests. Check out react-testing-library, though, you may find its testing philosophy beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

For the `close` action, I'd only test that it dispatches the two other actions - since this is all it really does. As explained by someone in a comment to your post, a unit test for an action creator shouldn't look past what this one function actually does.

You'll run into a problem when trying this with Jest though (or any testing library probably) if the sub-actions are written in the same module as `close`, it's not possible to mock them out easily.

Why would you mock them out? They might be more complicated and change state on their own, and also have their own dedicated unit test, so calling the original function in this unrelated test is not a good idea.

But there's a neat trick where you import the action creator module *in the same module*, and use that imported module reference to dispatch other actions:

```
import thisModule from './this_action_creator_module';

export const close = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(thisModule.closePopup());
        dispatch(thisModule.otherAction());
    }
}
```

Written in this fashion, you can mock specific actions exported by `this_action_creator_module`. This allows you to call `close` in a test and assert that it dispatches the mocks (which you defined) of the other two actions.

This is, in my opinion, the most complicated part of unit testing redux. The rest is pretty straight forward input-assertion-output.